# Power series expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to solve a equation which I have already solved using oDE but I want to solve it using a power series expansion but how do I express y as a power series?

Equation is as below

$$
(1+x) \, y'(x)=y(x)
$$

Comment: You write $y$ as power series with unknown coefficients and insert it into the ODE to get conditions on the unknowns. Then you try to solve this system to determine the unknown coefficients.

Comment: Sorry my question was more referring to how I write y as a power series

Comment: The question is not precise, you have to specify around which point you would like to have a solution. The answer strongly depend on this data.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look here first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series

Answer (score 0):

If you search online, you will find many sources and examples on the web. such as:

[Link 1](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-UseSeries-SolveDEs_Stu.pdf)

[Link 2](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/series/series03/series03.html)

Answer (score 0):

let $(a_n)$ so $$ y(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
then $$y'(x)=\sum_1^\infty a_nn(x-a)^{n-1}=\sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}$$
$$(1+x)y'(x)=y(x) \iff (1+x)\sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$\iff \sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}+\sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n+1}=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$\iff \sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}+\sum_1^\infty a_{n}nx^{n}=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$\iff a_1+\sum_1^\infty (a_{n+1}(n+1) + a_{n}n) x^{n}=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$\iff a_1=a_0 \; and \; \forall n \ge 1, a_{n+1}(n+1)=-a_n(n-1)$$
$$\iff a_1=a_0 \; and \; \forall n > 1, a_n=0$$

So $\forall f$ solution of the equation $\exists A\in\mathbb{R}$ / f(x)=A(x+1) and reciprocally , all these functions are solutions